# Why don't other infowindows hide when a new infowindo shows up in my code?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been adding google map with markers and infowindows. I made the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Info windows</title>
  <style>
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>

      // This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
      // When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.

      function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });

        var contentString = [];
        contentString[0] = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
        'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
        'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
        'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
        '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
        'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
        'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
        'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
        'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
        'Heritage Site.</p>'+
        '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
        '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

        contentString[1] = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">New York</h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p><b>New York</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
        'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
        'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
        'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
        '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
        'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
        'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
        'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
        'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
        'Heritage Site.</p>'+
        '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
        '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';



        var markers = [];

        markers[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map,
          title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
        });
        markers[1] = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: -20.363, lng: 120.044},
          map: map,
          title: 'New York'
        });
        function setwindow(i) {
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString[i],
            maxWidth: 200
          });
          markers[i].addListener('click', function() {          
            infowindow.open(markers[i].get('map'), this);
          });
        }

        for (var i = markers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
         setwindow(i);
        }








      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBga3chd-auBMGLGITc3rjact16mozcI4Q&callback=initMap">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have used only one `infowindow` variable. But when one infowindow is open and we click on other marker the previous infowindow doesn't hide. Both the new and old infowindow show up.

Google API's [official page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#add) says:

> For the best user experience, only one info window should be open on the map at any one time. Multiple info windows make the map appear cluttered. If you only need one info window at a time, **you can create just one InfoWindow object** and open it at different locations or markers upon map events, such as user clicks. If you do need more than one info window, you can display multiple InfoWindow objects at the same time.

This is exactly what I am doing. I have only one `infowindow` variable. So,

> Why don't other `infowindows` hide when a new `infowindow` shows up in my code?

From the answers it seems that each time the for loop runs it creates new `infowindow` objects without overriding the previous one.  I thought when the loop runs for the second time the first infowindow object is just overridden

> How can there be more than one `infowindow` objects with the same name?

Comment: Google API's official page clearly states it as Best practices: only one info window should be open on the map at any one time

Comment: It's been a year and you not selected an answer. If you solved the problem post the answer and accept your own answer.

Comment: @DipendraSingh I had solved it at that time with using closures somehow. But I need to revise everything again. Since I have been busy in my job, I couldn't revisit every question I asked. Anyways, I'll try to revise the problem once again in free time.

Answer (score 1):

Google API using infowindow Class to overlay some content on given marker or LatLong. In you example, *setwindow* function is responsible for associating infowindow object with Map UI and setting up content.

By looping this operation, JavaScript object once drawn on Map is now associated with it and if you re-initializing infowindow object(not Map drawn reference), it will be redrawn on Map. ([Function Scoping](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/#function-scope))

Instead, you should create infowindow object with empty content:

```
var markers = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: "",
     maxWidth: 200
});
```

And in *setwindow* function, you should set content only:

```
function setwindow(i) {
      markers[i].addListener('click', function() { 
         infowindow.setContent(contentString[i]); 
         infowindow.open(markers[i].get('map'), this);
      });
    }
```

Google API's official page clearly states it as Best practices: *only one info window should be open on the map at any one time*

Comment: I've edited the question. Could you explain How can there be more than one `infowindow` objects with the same name?

Comment: Is that answer what you are looking for?

Comment: I still don't understand how is javascript object drawn onto the map different from the one created by us. E.g. We created an infowindow variable and attached it to the marker variable then does google api creates a copy of it and laids out it onto the map? Does google api creates as many copies of infowindows as many markers are copied?

Comment: No. you are getting it wrong. there is no separate copy created. its a JavaScript function scoping, See section 2 for your query in my edited answer

Comment: In solution2 you are recreating `infowindow` in each iteration. In section one there was only one `infowindow` variable which was assigned different values in each iteration. If there are no seperate copies generated then how does function scoping acheive the same.

Comment: In section 1 infowindow object is globally available(not bound to function).
it is all about JavaScript Scoping. 
I wrote section 2 for your understanding, doesn't favor it.

Comment: In section 2 infowindow globally available but overwritten. But in your question  infowindow object scope limited to function.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are constructing infowindows for each markers. You should do something like this:

```
 ...
    var markers = [];

    markers[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map,
      title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });
    markers[1] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: -20.363, lng: 120.044},
      map: map,
      title: 'New York'
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({maxWidth: 200});
    function setwindow(i) {
      markers[i].addListener('click', function() {          
        infowindow.setContent(contentString[i]);
        infowindow.open(markers[i].get('map'), this);
      });
    }

    for (var i = markers.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     setwindow(i);
    }
 ...
```

Comment: But how can there be more than one `infowindow` objects with the same name? I thought when the loop runs for the second time the first `infowindow` object is just overridden.